# Searching elements in a XML

Tags: c#, xml, search, xml-parsing

I have a similar `XML` file which i required to search for its values .. as if for example when the Product Name is entered relevant price should be displayed

if there a easy way than **parsing** and search for values by loops ?

```
<products>
    <product>
      <Name> PRODUCT 1</Name>
      <price>150</price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <Name> PRODUCT 2</Name>
      <price>250</price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <Name> PRODUCT 3</Name>
      <price>300</price>
    </product>
  <products>
```

Comment: Sure you could scan it, thought that won't be very reliable.  Why wouldn't you want to parse it?  That sounds like a ridiculous requirement not to.

Comment: if its a larger XML file , processing time will be high isnt it ?

Comment: Good point but parsers don't necessarily have to parse the entire file and read it all into memory.  IIRC, both regular XML and LINQ to XML does not read all the data into memory at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to Xml is another possible solution that should minimise processing to the task at hand
see msdn for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387085.aspx

Comment: This is the best solution ! `LINQ` is great ! .. solved the prob using `LINQ`

Answer (score 5):

You can use XPath:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("myfile.xml");
XmlNode myPrice = doc.SelectSingleNode("/products/product[Name=' PRODUCT 1']/price");
Console.WriteLine(myPrice.InnerText);
```

outputs

```
150
```

Note that the whitespace before your product identifiers is significant.

You can do the same thing using XPathDocument, if you prefer:

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("myfile.xml");
XPathNavigator xpath = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator myPrice = xpath.SelectSingleNode("/products/product[Name=' PRODUCT 1']/price");
Console.WriteLine(myPrice.ToString());
```

also outputs

```
150
```

Tested both of these in .NET 2.0.

Comment: +1 works from .NET 1.x on while Linq-to-XML is handy but only available in .NET 3 and up

Comment: thanks for the answer these both snippets didnt work for me .. solved the problem using `LINQ`